# Can i lie to avoid a sin or to save myself from someone who i think is potentially a threat for me and for my religion

Tags: forgiveness

So this guy likes me and he goes home from the same route as me. I go home alone. He once approached me asked for my id and i didn't knew what to do (from where ppl commonly msg each other) and i gave him my id in the end then he told me that he liked me. I straight forwardly told him i don't. He kept telling me that we are just friends but being friends was also haram so i kept telling him that he will get hurt but he just didn't listen to me and kept messaging and waiting for me from i go. He kept paying my fare and he gave me gift that i rejected but he gave them to me anyways, he told me his intentions were to marry me but i did not find him safe. I was missing my prayers as well. After i watched a couple of videos and did some research i wanted to end this relationship or whatever it was but i was afraid of him approaching me again so i lied and told him that i am getting engaged to my cousin so that he leaves me alone and he surely did but now i feel guilty for lying. Please guide me in this case